Issue waiting for python server to start before creating electron browser window
I'm trying to implement a polling mechanism in my electron app that waits until my python server has started before creating the browser window. I need this because if the server is too slow to start, then I have to refresh the app in order for it to fetch the data from the server.
I implemented a 10 second timer. When I start the app with electron-forge start, the server is started after about 1 second. You can see this in the console window, and I'm able to successfully reach the health-check route in my chrome browser (the INFO lines in the console window are me refreshing my browser to prove I'm connected). For some reason, my implementation of the polling mechanism keeps checking until it reaches 10 seconds, and then the app quits.
I did do some googling and wasn't able to find an answer.
Question: Why isn't the mechanism stopping after the python server has started?
Here's my main.ts and console output:
// Electron modules
import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron';

// Built-in modules
import { spawn, exec } from 'child_process';
import path from 'path';

// Extra modules
import getPort, { portNumbers } from 'get-port';
import get from 'axios';


// Function to check if server is running
async function isServerRunning(serverUrl: string) {
  try {
    const response = await get(serverUrl);
    console.log(response);
    return response.status === 200;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

// Function to wait for the server to start
async function waitForServer(serverUrl: string) {
  const maxRetries = 10; // Set max retries
  let attempts = 0;

  while (attempts < maxRetries) {
    console.log(`Attempt #${attempts}`);
    const serverIsRunning = await isServerRunning(serverUrl);
    console.log(serverIsRunning);
    if (serverIsRunning) {
      return true; // Server is up
    }
    attempts++;
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // Wait 1 second before retrying
  }
  throw new Error('Waiting for server to start.');
}


const createWindow = (port: number) => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: false,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL);
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile(
      path.join(__dirname, `../renderer/${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_NAME}/index.html`),
    );
  }
};


app.whenReady().then(async () => {
  const port = 8036;

  // Start the flask server in development or production
  if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    spawn(`python backend/main.py ${port}`, {
      detached: true,
      shell: true,
      stdio: 'inherit',
    });
  } else {
    ...
  }

  try {
    await waitForServer(`http://localhost:${port}/health-check`);
    createWindow(port);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    app.quit();
  }

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow(port);
  });

  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit();
    }
  });
});

Console output:
✔ Checking your system
✔ Locating application
✔ Loading configuration
✔ Preparing native dependencies [0.2s]
✔ Running generateAssets hook
⠙ [plugin-vite] Launching dev servers for renderer process code
◼ [plugin-vite] Compiling main process code
✔ [plugin-vite] Launching dev servers for renderer process code [0.1s]
⠸ [plugin-vite] Compiling main process code
vite v4.4.9 building for development...

watching for file changes...
vite v4.4.9 building for development...

watching for file changes...

build started...

build started...
✓ 1 modules transformed.
Generated an empty chunk: "preload".
✔ [plugin-vite] Launching dev servers for renderer process code [0.1s]
✔ [plugin-vite] Launching dev servers for renderer process code [0.1s]
⠧ [plugin-vite] Compiling main process code
✔ [plugin-vite] Launching dev servers for renderer process code [0.1s]
✔ [plugin-vite] Compiling main process code [0.8s]

2024-09-26 22:54:06.322 Electron[22787:10970072] WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.
Attempt #0
false
INFO:     Started server process [22790]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8036 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Attempt #1
false
Attempt #2
false
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53635 - "GET /health-check HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Attempt #3
false
Attempt #4
false
Attempt #5
false
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53635 - "GET /health-check HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Attempt #6
false
Attempt #7
false
Attempt #8
false
Attempt #9
false
Error: Waiting for server to start.
    at Oo (/repopath/.vite/build/main.js:21:7777)
    at async /repopath/.vite/build/main.js:21:8504


I believe there are two issues:

a new async function was needed to start the python server and
instead of using http://localhost:xxx, use http://127.0.0.1:xxx.

The first change wasn't enough to get the code working, but after doing some more research, it seems like axios has issues with using localhost, so switching it to 127.0.0.1 worked.
main.ts:
import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron';
import { spawn, exec } from 'child_process';
import path from 'path';
import axios from 'axios';

const PORT = 8036;

// Function to check if python server is running
async function isServerRunning(url: string) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    return response.status === 200;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

// Function to ping server to see if it is running
async function waitForServer(url: string) {
  const maxRetries = 20; // Set max retries
  let attempts = 0;

  while (attempts < maxRetries) {
    console.log(`Attempt #${attempts + 1}`);
    const isRunning = await isServerRunning(url);
    if (isRunning) {
      return true;
    }
    attempts++;
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
  throw new Error('Unable to connect to server.');
}

// Function to start server in dev or production
async function startServer() {
  if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    spawn('python backend/main.py', {
      detached: true,
      shell: true,
      stdio: 'inherit',
    });
  } else {
    ...
  }
}

// Shut down server and electron
const shutdown = () => {
  // Kill app executable if production
  if (!MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    const killcmd = {
      darwin: 'killall App',
      linux: '',
      win32: 'taskkill /f /t /im App.exe',
      aix: undefined,
      android: undefined,
      cygwin: undefined,
      freebsd: undefined,
      haiku: undefined,
      netbsd: undefined,
      openbsd: undefined,
      sunos: undefined,
    }[process.platform];

    exec(killcmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    });
  }

  axios
    .get(`http://127.0.0.1:${PORT}/quit`)
    .then(() => app.quit())
    .catch(() => app.quit());
};

if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: false,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL);
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile(
      path.join(__dirname, `../renderer/${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_NAME}/index.html`),
    );
  }

};

app.whenReady().then(async () => {
  await startServer();

  try {
    await waitForServer(`http://127.0.0.1:${PORT}/health-check`);
    createWindow();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    app.quit();
  }

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });

  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      shutdown();
    }
  });
});

